# VBA Macro If cell found in multiple cells then

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2007, vba

i need help with the below if then statement.  will try and explain as best as i can.

cells E21 and F21 is merged and the value varies.  i have a list of numbers underneath each other from o1 to o100 and the same for p q r s t u that the values are constant.

i need a macro to check in which column the value in cell E21 is and put the number (that is in the macro) in cell E23(also merged with F23).

below is the macro that works if it only checks cell o1 but it does not work if i change it to o1:o100.  the macro is very basic and only the first piece.  please can you tell me how to get the macro to search the entire list.

```
Sub RunSelect()

    If Range("E21").Value = Range("o1:o100").Value Then
        Range("E23").Value = "3"

    ElseIf Range("E21").Value = Range("p1:p100").Value Then
        Range("E23").Value = "4"

    Else: MsgBox ("Incorrect number entered")

    End If

End Sub
```

thanks for all the help

Comment: it's a bit unclear... to me :( O1 to O100 is a range and if any cell in that range matches to E21 you want to get...what? why 3? why 4?...

Comment: sorry, realized out of context it does not make any sense,  just a bit of info so other people can make use of it.  each vehicle has a number from 3 to 9 and each location has a 4 digit number.  all locations are listed in collumns o to u.  we only work with numbers.  the vehicles only go to certain locations and if we receive an order we need to check on which vehicle it needs to go.  the spreadsheet already inputs all other details so this will make it easier for the new staff to check where to send the papers and not go through the whole list everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not ENTIRELY sure what you're looking for, but you need to write a For Each...Next loop to loop through each cell and check it's value. Excel doesn't know you want to look at each cell in those ranges, therefore you need to tell it to using a loop.

Trying working with this.

```
For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("O1:O100").Cells
     If c.Value = Range("E21").Value Then Range("E23").Value = "3"
        Next
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: works perfectly,  exactly what i needed.  thanks for the site as well.  it is the reason why i keep coming back to stackoverflow.  i dont just get answers, i get the explanations and understanding with it.